# How to proxy WebSocket via Apache to Play-Framework

Tags: https, playframework, websocket, mod-proxy, playframework-2.5

I'm stuck with my Apache-config and appreciate any help on this.

The config is like this:

- The Apache redirects all http traffic to https
- It proxies requests like https://domain.tld/app1 to http://domain.tld:9000/app1 (play apps are running at app-context /app*/...)

This works very well with the following Apache-config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    Redirect permanent / https://domain.tld/
    Redirect permanent / https://domain.tld/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
#ssl-config here
<Proxy http://localhost:9000/*>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass         /app1  http://domain.tld:9000/app1
ProxyPassReverse  /app1  http://domain.tld:9000/app1
ProxyPassReverse  /app1  http://domain.tld/app1
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem ist, that one play-application got a WebSocket added. Which isn't working with the above setup. So I read the stuff on the [play-pages](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/HTTPServer). Which led me to install mod_proxy_wstunnel. I also add the following lines to the config, but had no success with that:

```
ProxyPass         /app1/timerWs ws://domain.tld:9000/app1/timerWs
ProxyPassReverse  /app1/timerWs ws://domain.tld:9000/app1/timerWs
```

When I'm trying to connect to https://domain.tld/rlc/timerWs I got an 500 Internal Server Error, but there are no new, more specific errors in the apache error log.

How can I configure Apache to proxy WebSocket requests properly to my play applications?

My play-apps do not have https-adapters. All the https stuff is done by the Apache-proxy.

Play-apps are on version 2.5.
Apache is on 2.4.7.

Thanks a lot for your help.
Tobias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue now. What did the trick was to set-up https not only on the Apache, but also on Plays application server Jetty. To do so see this [link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ConfiguringHttps). This leads to another ProxyPass address (notice the wss instead of ws):

```
ProxyPass         /app1/timerWs wss://domain.tld:9000/app1/timerWs
ProxyPassReverse  /app1/timerWs wss://domain.tld:9000/app1/timerWs
```

I also had to change the WebSocket address in my Javascript, to let the Browser know, where to find the WebSocket-Backend.

```
$(function() {
    var WS = window['MozWebSocket'] ? MozWebSocket : WebSocket
    var dateSocket = new WS("wss://domain.tld/rlc/timerWs")
    var receiveEvent = function(event) {
        $("#timer").html(event.data);
    }
    dateSocket.onmessage = receiveEvent
});
```

Before that I used a Play-route `@routes.Application.timerWs().webSocketURL(request)` to address the WebSocket.